# Download svg created by d3js as svg file with another svg in it

Tags: javascript, svg

I created a download function for my svg graph, it successfully download the svg file, but there is another svg icon in the svg tag disappear.

[image]

```js
document.querySelector(".download").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const svgElement = document.querySelector("svg");
  const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
  const blob = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = "my_svg_file.svg";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```html
<div>
  <svg width="300" height="200">
    <rect stroke="black" x="20" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="navy"></rect>
    <rect stroke="black" x="200" y="0" width="50" height="200" fill="brown"></rect>
    <clipPath id="icon-4-29">
      <rect class="icon" width="26.095396561286744" height="26.09539656128674" x="0" y="0"></rect>
    </clipPath>
    <image xlink:href="https://expo.taiwan-healthcare.org//data/tmp/20230413/202304131zc6g3.svg" visibility="visible" clip-path="url(#icon-4-29)" width="26.095396561286744" height="26.09539656128674" x="0" y="0"></image>
  </svg>
</div>

<button class="download">download</button>
```

I tried to copy the `path` from svg icon, change the number in the path to get the size I expect, paste it to svg tag then download it.

But it will change the curve setting (ex: `A4.61,4.61,0,0,1,.59,37.34`) and mass the shape.

```js
const svg1 = `
<path d="M42.39,42H5.2A4.61,4.61,0,0,1,.59,37.34V5.57A4.61,4.61,0,0,1,5.2,1H42.39A4.6,4.6,0,0,1,47,5.57V37.34A4.6,4.6,0,0,1,42.39,42"/>
<path d="M23.58,14.69c1.9-1.91,3.83-3.77,5.67-5.71a6.79,6.79,0,0,1,5.12-2.17c2.13,0,4.27,0,6.39,0a5.76,5.76,0,0,1,5.54,4.78c.38,3.07-1.41,6.06-4.22,6.64a18.62,18.62,0,0,1-4.42.12A3.32,3.32,0,0,0,35,19.47C29.43,25.06,23.83,30.6,18.26,36.18a7,7,0,0,1-5.37,2.22c-2,0-3.89,0-5.84,0a5.94,5.94,0,0,1-5.7-5.82,5.77,5.77,0,0,1,5.54-5.81c1.2,0,2.41.05,3.61,0A2.49,2.49,0,0,0,12,26.13c1.68-1.59,3.31-3.23,4.91-4.91A2,2,0,0,0,17.39,20c.05-2.22,0-4.45,0-6.67s1.71-3.68,3.74-3.18a2.73,2.73,0,0,1,2.2,2.73c0,.57,0,1.15,0,1.73l.2.13M10.29,35.43c.77,0,1.55,0,2.32,0a4.79,4.79,0,0,0,3.95-1.61C22.12,28.19,27.78,22.61,33.36,17a4.67,4.67,0,0,1,3.77-1.58c1.11.06,2.22,0,3.34,0a2.76,2.76,0,0,0,2.88-2.92,2.84,2.84,0,0,0-2.9-2.72c-2,0-4,0-6,0a4,4,0,0,0-3.12,1.31c-5.8,5.86-11.65,11.67-17.47,17.51a3.92,3.92,0,0,1-3,1.24c-1.2,0-2.41,0-3.61,0-1.82,0-2.89,1-2.89,2.65a2.86,2.86,0,0,0,2.87,3c1,0,2,0,3.06,0"/>
<path d="M20.48,3.53a3.09,3.09,0,0,1,3,3.08,3,3,0,0,1-3.11,3,3,3,0,0,1-2.91-3.09,3.12,3.12,0,0,1,3.06-3"/>
<path d="M31.58,35.13c1.86-1.86,3.52-3.51,5.16-5.16.24-.24.49-.47.72-.73a1.45,1.45,0,0,0,.08-2.13,1.41,1.41,0,0,0-2.06.17c-1.67,1.64-3.32,3.31-5,5a8.63,8.63,0,0,0-.62.81l-.32-.13c0-.9,0-1.8,0-2.69s-.45-1.43-1.29-1.45a1.22,1.22,0,0,0-1.39,1.27c0,2.1-.05,4.2,0,6.29a1.4,1.4,0,0,0,1.54,1.5c2.06,0,4.13,0,6.19,0a1.24,1.24,0,0,0,1.32-1.35,1.29,1.29,0,0,0-1.4-1.38c-.89,0-1.78,0-3,0"/>
`;

const multipliedSvg = svg1.replace(/(\d+\.\d+|\d+)/g, (match) => parseFloat(match) * 10);
```

```html
<svg>
<path d="M423.9,420H52A46.1,46.1,0,0,10,.590,373.40000000000003V55.7A46.1,46.1,0,0,10,52,10H423.9A46,46,0,0,10,470,55.7V373.40000000000003A46,46,0,0,10,423.9,420"/>
<path d="M235.79999999999998,146.9c19-19.099999999999998,38.3-37.7,56.7-57.1a67.9,67.9,0,0,10,51.2-21.7c21.299999999999997,0,42.699999999999996,0,63.9,0a57.599999999999994,57.599999999999994,0,0,10,55.4,47.800000000000004c.380,30.7-14.1,60.599999999999994-42.199999999999996,66.39999999999999a186.20000000000002,186.20000000000002,0,0,10-44.2.120A33.199999999999996,33.199999999999996,0,0,0,350,194.7C294.3,250.6,238.29999999999998,306,182.60000000000002,361.8a70,70,0,0,10-53.7,22.200000000000003c-20,0-38.9,0-58.4,0a59.400000000000006,59.400000000000006,0,0,10-57-58.2,57.699999999999996,57.699999999999996,0,0,10,55.4-58.099999999999994c12,0,24.1.50,36.1,0A24.900000000000002,24.900000000000002,0,0,0,120,261.3c16.8-15.9,33.1-32.3,49.1-49.1A20,20,0,0,0,173.9,200c.50-22.200000000000003,0-44.5,0-66.7s17.1-36.800000000000004,37.400000000000006-31.8a27.3,27.3,0,0,10,22,27.3c0,.570,0,11.5,0,17.3l.21.299999999999997M102.89999999999999,354.3c.770,0,15.5,0,23.2,0a47.9,47.9,0,0,0,39.5-16.1C221.20000000000002,281.90000000000003,277.8,226.1,333.6,170a46.7,46.7,0,0,10,37.7-15.8c11.100000000000001.60,22.200000000000003,0,33.4,0a27.599999999999998,27.599999999999998,0,0,0,28.799999999999997-29.2,28.4,28.4,0,0,0-29-27.200000000000003c-20,0-40,0-60,0a40,40,0,0,0-31.200000000000003,13.100000000000001c-58,58.6-116.5,116.7-174.7,175.10000000000002a39.2,39.2,0,0,10-30,12.4c-12,0-24.1,0-36.1,0-18.2,0-28.900000000000002,10-28.900000000000002,26.5a28.599999999999998,28.599999999999998,0,0,0,28.700000000000003,30c10,0,20,0,30.6,0"/>
<path d="M204.8,35.3a30.9,30.9,0,0,10,30,30.8,30,30,0,0,10-31.099999999999998,30,30,30,0,0,10-29.1-30.9,31.200000000000003,31.200000000000003,0,0,10,30.6-30"/>
<path d="M315.79999999999995,351.3c18.6-18.6,35.2-35.099999999999994,51.6-51.6.240-.244.89999999999998-.477.2-.730a14.5,14.5,0,0,0,.80-21.299999999999997,14.1,14.1,0,0,0-20.6.170c-16.7,16.4-33.199999999999996,33.1-50,50a86.30000000000001,86.30000000000001,0,0,0-.628.1l-.320-.130c0-.90,0-18,0-26.9s-.450-14.299999999999999-12.9-14.5a12.2,12.2,0,0,0-13.899999999999999,12.7c0,21-.50,42,0,62.9a14,14,0,0,0,15.4,15c20.6,0,41.3,0,61.900000000000006,0a12.4,12.4,0,0,0,13.200000000000001-13.5,12.9,12.9,0,0,0-14-13.799999999999999c-.890,0-17.8,0-30,0"/>
</svg>
```

Is there any way to download the svg with `<image>` in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scaling function doesn't work because you're multiplying all command values.

The 4th (long arc flag) and 5th (sweep flag) values in an [`A` Arc command](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) only accept the values **1 or 0**;

By setting a different value you're actually prevent this segment from being rendered. You'll also see an error log in your console like:

> Error:  attribute d: Expected number,
> "…3.40000000000003V55.7A46.1,46.1,…".

### Alternative

You can either

- fetch the external svg and embed it via dataURL
- or embed the svg as a `<symbol>` or nested `<svg>`

### Fetch external and create data url

This approach requires your external svg to be on **same domain** or hosted on a server allowing **cross origin access** – otherwise you'll get a **CORS** error

```js
const btnDownload = document.querySelector(".download");
const svgElement = document.querySelector("svg");

// embed external images
embedExternalImagesAsDataURL(svgElement);


async function embedExternalImagesAsDataURL(svg) {
  let images = svg.querySelectorAll("image");
  images.forEach(async (image) => {
    let href = image.getAttribute("xlink:href");
    let fetched = await fetch(href);
    let markup = await fetched.text();
    // create data url
    let dataURL = `data:image/svg+xml, ` + encodeURIComponent(markup);
    // replace external href with data url
    image.setAttribute("xlink:href", dataURL);
  });
}

btnDownload.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
  const blob = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = "my_svg_file.svg";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```html
  <svg id="svg" width="300" height="200">
    <rect stroke="black" x="20" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="navy"></rect>
    <rect stroke="black" x="200" y="0" width="50" height="200" fill="brown"></rect>
    <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg" visibility="visible" width="26.095396561286744" height="26.09539656128674" x="0" y="0"></image>
  </svg>

<button class="download">download</button>
```

### Embed as `<symbol>`

Similar to the first approach we're fetching the external svg.
This time we're creating a `<symbol>` and a `<use>`element replacing the `<image>`.
It is important to copy some of the images attributes most importantly x,y, width and height and ideally the `viewBox` attribute – otherwise the embedded element will have different placement and size.

```js
const btnDownload = document.querySelector(".download");
const svgElement = document.querySelector("svg");

// embed external images
embedExternalImagesAsNestedSVG(svgElement);

async function embedExternalImagesAsNestedSVG(svg) {
  const ns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
  let images = svg.querySelectorAll("image");
  images.forEach(async (image) => {
    let href = image.getAttribute("xlink:href");
    let fetched = await fetch(href);
    let markup = await fetched.text();
    // create data url
    let externalSVG = new DOMParser()
      .parseFromString(markup, "image/svg+xml")
      .querySelector("svg");

    let symbol = document.createElementNS(ns, "symbol");
    symbol.setAttribute("viewBox", externalSVG.getAttribute("viewBox"));
    symbol.id = "external";
    symbol.innerHTML = externalSVG.innerHTML;
    let use = document.createElementNS(ns, "use");
    use.setAttribute("xlink:href", "#external");
    use.setAttribute("href", "#external");

    // copy attributes like width and height
    use.setAttribute("x", image.x.baseVal.value);
    use.setAttribute("y", image.y.baseVal.value);
    use.setAttribute("width", image.width.baseVal.value);
    use.setAttribute("height", image.height.baseVal.value);

    svg.insertBefore(symbol, svg.children[0]);
    image.replaceWith(use);

  });
}


btnDownload.addEventListener("click", () => {
  const svgString = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svgElement);
  const blob = new Blob([svgString], {
    type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement("a");
  link.href = url;
  link.download = "my_svg_file.svg";
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
});
```

```html
  <svg id="svg" width="300" height="200">
    <rect stroke="black" x="20" y="50" width="200" height="100" fill="navy"></rect>
    <rect stroke="black" x="200" y="0" width="50" height="200" fill="brown"></rect>
    <image xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/4f/SVG_Logo.svg" visibility="visible" width="26.095396561286744" height="26.09539656128674" x="0" y="0"></image>
  </svg>

<button class="download">download</button>
```

#### Drawbacks: conflicting CSS styles or duplicate IDs

The external svg might accidentally use class names or Ids that are also used in the parent SVG.
This will lead to overridden styling, wrong gradient fills or incorrect masking clipping.

So a data URL is probably the more robust solution.

Comment: Fun fact: scaling all `d` values would usually work even for mixed commands combining relative and absolute values – unless you're using `A` arc commands. So the rule of thumb: always consider exceptions for arc commands - they are quite special.